# Hexagonal Warping

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators

Hexagonal warping had observed in $Bi_2Te_3$. Is it related somehow with the topological insulator type?
Is it a characteristic of weak topological insulator or are there other reasons for this phenomenon?

Comment: You mean hexagonal warping of the band structure? This is just determined by the underlying symmetry group.

Comment: I mean the section at Fermi surface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hexagonal warping is not related to topololgical insulators. Hexagonal (or trigonal) warping is just an expression of the underlying crystal symmetry. Say I have a three-fold rotation axis in a two dimensional crystal  with a band minimum at $k=0$. The dispersion $\varepsilon(k_x,k_y)$ around the band minimum must be,

$$\varepsilon = k_x^2 + k_y^2 + \beta(k_x^3 - 3k_y^2k_2) + O(k^4)$$

by symmetry. If $|k| \ll \beta $ then we can neglect the cubic terms and the result will be rotationally symmetric. As we increase $|k|$, the cubic terms will became relevant and the band structure will become warped into a triangular shape, which is what we would expect from the underlying symmetry.

Nothing here is particular to the example I wrote, and therefore you would expect the same thing to happen with, say, Dirac cones in a topological insulator, if the underlying crystal lattice was trigonal.